# If else statement not triggering with $query->num_rows()

Tags: php

I have two MySQL queries to fetch data from a table.

Individually, the `if ($query_one->num_rows() > 0)` and/or `if ($query_two->num_rows() > 0)` work perfectly.

**The Problem:** However, when used in an **elseif statement** only the first query `$query_one->num_rows()` fetches data. If the first query has no results, the second query `$query_two->num_rows()` should trigger?

```
if ($query_one->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query_one->row(0)->total;
    }
    else if($query_two->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query_two->row(0)->total;
    }

    return 0;
```

I know there are posts on stackoverflow that show the correct way to implementing an elseif statement with queries, but I have already read them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So.. The second query never gets triggered?

Comment: The code inside the brackets `{}` will only run if the code inside the parentheses `()` evaluates to `true`. Are you sure `$query_two->num_rows()` is greater than `0`?

Comment: Try using `mysql_num_rows($query_two) > 0`  and `mysql_num_rows($query_one) > 0`.

Comment: Or $query_one->num_rows() is ALWAYS > 0

Comment: `$query_two->num_rows()` is definitely not 0, because when used without elseif statement, it returns true

Comment: What do you expect to occur here? Since it seems like your first condition will never be false thus everything will always go there.

Comment: this question should be simply closed

Comment: Why is everyone so mad. There is a simple problem here. The first condition is not always true, it false when there is nothing fetched. However, the second condition is not triggered...

Answer (score -1):

Try this way so that you would know where it goes:

```
if ($query_one->num_rows() > 0)
{
    echo "query_one run";
    return $query_one->row(0)->total;
}
else 
{
    if($query_two->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       echo "query_two run";
       return $query_two->row(0)->total;
    }
    else
   {
      echo "nothing to return";
      return 0;
   }
}
```

Just remove the echo when you find out what is wrong.
Maybe both the query does not return anything.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i feel like this isnt best practice. It's more code than needed

Comment: how can you even fix the code if you don't know what is wrong with your code?